# i cant get the Lat/Lng of a dragged marker in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

i have created this pretty simple application ( you choose cities and it's shown on the map and you can drag the marker to your location),
it's here http://jsfiddle.net/shoya/ZW9jP/200/ ,and there is this part that writes Lat/Lng of the point you dragged marker to in a div for further use, it works perfect in chrome and ff and opera but not in IE,why? i mean it doesn't write the Lat/Lng in IE.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> not in IE, why?

IE is different from standards compliant browsers and usually requires special coding.

> what am i doing wrong?

This is the javascript error that IE reports:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method  LayoutCM.js, line 195 character 5
```

But it does seem to be writing the coordinates into the div, at least in IE8.  Which version of IE are you having trouble with?